# SharePoint permission list-item level

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, content-query-web-part, item-level-permissions

I have a list of projects with three different status based on the user permission. What I want is that some list items will show to the user based on their permission and the rest will be hidden. Is this possible?

Possible to use a web part content query to extract items from a list based on their permission? Or any other way?

Comment: This is default behavior. If you use item level permission only items that users has access to will be shown (regardless in is it list view web part of content query). Are you hitting any issues with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript code as below:

```
function breakInheritance() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestList');

    this.item = oList.getItemById(2);

    // Break inheritance. If argument is 'true' then parent list
    // permissions are kept as is. If 'false' then parent list 
    // permission are removed.
    item.breakRoleInheritance(true);

    this.oUser = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser('DOMAIN\\user');
    var collRoleDefinitionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
    this.roleDefs = clientContext.get_web().get_roleDefinitions();

    //Assign 'Reader' permission level to user
    //collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(roleDefs.getByType(SP.RoleType.reader));

    //Assign '<CUSTOM PERMISSION LEVEL>' permission level to user
    collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(roleDefs.getByName("<CUSTOM PERMISSION LEVEL>"));

    item.get_roleAssignments().add(oUser, collRoleDefinitionBinding);

    clientContext.load(oUser);
    clientContext.load(item);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    console.log(item);

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

[Reference MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185013(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: @Arte2 Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!'

Answer (score 1):

For classic view, you could hide list item by [CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views).

Below is sample script to hide list item if user have not edit permission for list item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        function OnPostRenderTemplate(ctx) {
            SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadContext, 'sp.js');
            function loadContext() {
                var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
                var call = jQuery.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                        "/_api/Web/effectiveBasePermissions",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                });
                var manageLists;
                call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var manageListsPerms = new SP.BasePermissions();
                    manageListsPerms.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);
                    manageLists = manageListsPerms.has(SP.PermissionKind.manageLists);
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = document.getElementById(GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]));
                    if (manageLists) {
                        row.style.display = 'block';
                    } else {
                        row.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        function RegisterListViewTemplate() {
            var viewContext = {};
            viewContext.Templates = {};
            viewContext.Templates.OnPostRender = OnPostRenderTemplate;
            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(viewContext);
        }
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RegisterListViewTemplate, 'clienttemplates.js');
    })();        
</script>
```